# I need JavaScript (Angular) event listener for closing page and tabs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need event that will work on closing page or tab, but also will not trigger on refreshing page. I know for "beforeunload", but that still work on refreshing page.

Here is my code

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
checkIsUserLogOut() {
    if (ConfigurationModel.applicationOptions.autoLogOutWhenWebBrowserClosed) {
        localStorage.removeItem('auth_token');
        localStorage.removeItem('auth_token_expires_on');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an [article](https://www.angularfix.com/2021/09/how-can-i-handle-browser-tab-close.html) for this *exact* problem (does not want to trigger code on refresh).

It uses a `localStorage` variable to save the datetime of the last `unload` event, and if its less than a preset amount of time it considers it a refresh.

the `unload` event handler:

```
function unload(event) {
    if (window.localStorage) {
        // flag the page as being unloading
        window.localStorage['myUnloadEventFlag']=new Date().getTime();
    }

    askServerToDisconnectUserInAFewSeconds(); // synchronous AJAX call

}
```

on page load:

```
function myLoad(event) {
    if (window.localStorage) {
        var t0 = Number(window.localStorage['myUnloadEventFlag']);
        if (isNaN(t0)) t0=0;
        var t1=new Date().getTime();
        var duration=t1-t0;
        if (duration<10*1000) {
            // less than 10 seconds since the previous Unload event => it's a browser reload (so cancel the disconnection request)
            askServerToCancelDisconnectionRequest(); // asynchronous AJAX call
        } else {
            // last unload event was for a tab/window close => do whatever
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank but It didn't help, I found this solution
for reloading page
  let pageReloaded = window.performance
   .getEntriesByType('navigation')
   .map((nav) => (nav as any).type)
   .includes('reload');